# ASP.NET vs JQuery to create web page with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic

i want to build an asp.net webpage. it will be used as a form to collect some information from user and submit it to be saved on database.

content of the page controls and labels should be created dynamically.

Questions of the form will be read from database. Answers are either free text or multi-choice. Type of the answer will specify the type of the control used to get the answer (textboxes , radioButtons).

should i create asp.net controls on page_load or should i create HTML controls using JQUERY on $(document).ready.. ?

choosing between asp.net and JQuery will affect next steps, such as validation, collecting controls values and submitting.

any suggestions please? comparison would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your form based on? If you want to create it dynamically there has to be some logic for creating it. I am assuming you're thinking of Web Forms if you're talking about page_load? It would help to see some code.

Comment: FWIW choosing between ASP.NET and jQuery won't affect validation. You *should* validate on the client side for the users-sake, and *definitely* validate on the server side for yours.

Comment: controls have to be dynamic because questions that will be asked on the form are dynamic. questions will be read from  database, along with their type (i.e. free text , multiple choice..)
i haven't written code for the page yet, because i need to choose technology first

Comment: @Nina You've already answered your question. You have to use both (well, you could do without jQuery, but it will likely make things easier, depending on how you implement). You simply need to get started and if you have problems, post them here. Voting to close as "Opinion based", as we can't really tell you want framework to use. But comparing jQuery to ASP.NET is like comparing hotdogs to daschunds.

Comment: @Nina i will suggest to make a usercontrol for each answer type you have and you will write the validation inside this user control, and when you load the questions, you can show the answer zone based on the question answer type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your controls are not pre-decided and you need to add them dynamically. Then I would suggest you to use JQUERY.

WHY:

Because whether you add your controls in c# or in JQUERY, you have to use Js ultimately to Validate, get controls data etc. As controls added to page's control collection using c# at runtime, will not be available through postbacks. You have to re-add them on every postback.

Another option can be to use jTemplate, because it is easy to play around with jTemplate on client-side.

http://jtemplates.tpython.com/

http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/18/jtemplates-with-jquery-ajax-and-json/

Comment: assuming that i am gonna use JQUERY : questions, choices and labels that will be displayed on the form have to be read from database. is it efficient to use $ajax inside $(document).ready to retrieve all that information, and then build controls on success based on returned data?

Comment: Yes, it is. You start doing that and can post problems you face on stackoverflow to address them particularly.

Comment: i have tried such thing for displaying about 5 to 6 textareas.
on $(document).ready : i call $ajax to retrieve those 5 questions and create textareas for answers. when the page is called for the first time, it gets displayed empty to the user, and it takes a few seconds to display controls. is that normal? in consequent calls for the page, controls are displayed faster.

Comment: Instead of ajax you can also load questions on page load and pass them to JS using jason. There are multiple approaches for multiple scenarios. Please post your issue as new question.

Comment: i used jquery to create html controls on my (.aspx) page.
the question is : how to submit values of these controls to the server (to the same page) ? 
p.s: html controls are created in a content page. i want to submit them using an html submit button

Comment: Easiest way is to append your data using js to some serverControl hidden field and on server split that data like on pipe | character. e.g 'Amer'|'123'|'56$'

Answer (score 0):

There many things you can do on both sides. The dynamic things that will be rendering, it's there any structure in the code or it will be totally random data. To create view base on data with ASP.NET i will recommend you to use MVC to render the view like you want depending on the data (model).

You can also generated html easily using jquery. There's also framework avalable to generate you html depending on the model like AngularJS.

Personnaly, if you don't want to use a javascript framework, i will generate the html in jquery. It's easy to append and bind event on it like so :

```
$("#MyContainer").append("<div id='test' >my content</div>");
```